# Set body class with jquery cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to create a "highcontrast" style switcher with [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

I've been busting my head for couple of hours now, read a lot of questions on stackoverflow.com, but I didn't solve my problem.

Idea is to toggle class "highcontrast" on body tag when clicking on span element with id "switch". Inside CSS stylesheet I have set of rules which I want to apply if body tag has class "highcontrast".

This is jQuery code for above scenario:

```
$("#switch").click(function () {
    $.cookie('bodyclass', 'highcontrast', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    $('body').toggleClass('highcontrast');
});
```

If you click on switch element body class is toggled.
Now if you go to another page, the cookie is there and the value is set, but body class "highcontrast" is no longer present.

What I'm I missing?

Comment: Can you show the code where you read the cookie value and set the class on the body on page load?

Comment: your toggleClass works on click as per the code, so moving to other page wont trigger the click automatically..!

Comment: missing code to read cookie when page loads and if it exists change body class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, this is verified and working...

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Style Switcher</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../plugins/cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="switch.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<span id="switch">Switch</span>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Check (onLoad) if the cookie is there and set the class if it is
        if ($.cookie('highcontrast') == "yes") {
            $("body").addClass("highcontrast");
        }

        // When the span is clicked
        $("#switch").click(function () {
            // Check the current cookie value
            // If the cookie is empty or set to no, then add highcontrast
            if ($.cookie('highcontrast') == "undefined" || $.cookie('highcontrast') == "no") {
                // Set cookie value to yes
                $.cookie('highcontrast','yes', {expires: 7, path: '/'});
                // Add the class to the body
                $("body").addClass("highcontrast");
            }
            // If the cookie was already set to yes then remove it
            else {
                $.cookie('highcontrast','no',  {expires: 7, path: '/'});
                $("body").removeClass("highcontrast");
            }
        }); 
    });
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    body.highcontrast {
        background-color:#000;
        color:#fff;
    }
```

Comment: I tested your solution and it seems to work perfectly.
Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. It could definitely be cleaned up with some variables, but that is the basic idea... Enjoy!

Comment: I would look at the plugin documentation to see if the "expires" value should be removed from the click event (if the cookie already exists)... you can use the Google Chrome "Inspect" panel to view cookies (Right Click > Inspect Element > Resources > Cookies) and check if the expires date gets set back to seven days everytime you click the span. (You may or may not want this to happen).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, on your page load:

```
if ( $.cookie('bodyclass') ) {
    $('body').toggleClass('highcontrast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `highcontrast` depending on what the user wants, and read it on page load.

```
// switch cookie
$("#switch").click(function() {

    // check current cookie
    var current = $.cookie('highcontrast');

    // set new cookie and adjust contrast
    if (current) {

        // remove cookie
        $.cookie('highcontrast', null);

        // remove class
        $('body').removeClass('highcontrast');

    } else {

        // add cookie
        $.cookie('highcontrast', 1, { expires: 7, path: '/' });

        // add class
        $('body').addClass('highcontrast');
    }

});

// set contrast on page load
$(function() {

    var value = $.cookie('highcontrast');

    if (value) {

        // add contrast class
        $('body').addClass('highcontrast');

    }

});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the problem was this:
If you click on a #switch element for 2nd time (1st time you set body class to "highcontrast"), body class gets removed, but probably in this case cookie should be removed also, because when you go to another page, body class is there again.

Answer (score 0):

On `document.ready` check for cookies preset and values are set if its present then add it to body.

**Example**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($.cookie('bodyclass'))
   {
       $('body').addClass($.cookie('bodyclass'));
   }
});
```